# Can we return values in between when stored procedure is running?

Tags: c#

I have a scenario where I have multiple stored procedures written in another stored procedure and I want to return some values after executing each stored procedure and want to display the value in my windows application. Is it possible?

Suppose the stored procedure is as below

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ProcedureName AS BEGIN    
    EXEC storedProcedureName1    
    EXEC storedProcedureName2    
    EXEC storedProcedureName3
END
```

So I will call `procedureName` stored procedure from application but want to display some status when `storedprocedureName1` is completed without waiting for whole stored procedure to get executed and so on for other remaining stored procedures. So how can I achieve this?

Comment: For what **database system** is this?? Calling and handling stored procedures is highly vendor-specific - we need to know if this is for MySQL, Oracle, IBM DB2, SQL Server, Postgres or something else....

Answer (score 0):

if you're using SQL Server, it's possible

**short answer**:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ProcedureName AS
BEGIN    
    EXEC storedProcedureName1
    raiserror('Proc1 completed, 0, 0) with nowait
    EXEC storedProcedureName2    
    raiserror('Proc2 completed, 0, 0) with nowait
    EXEC storedProcedureName3
END
```

**long answer**: see [SQL Server stored procedure that returns processed records number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12996705/sql-server-stored-procedure-that-returns-processed-records-number/12997049#12997049)

Comment: The `raiserror` as defined `Generates an error message and initiates error processing for the session` should not be used for such operations.

Comment: Well I'll be glad if you could suggest another solution

Comment: print is not an option, it will not print immediately

Comment: That fairly true with nowait option.